# Django Rest Framework MultipleChoiceField with dynamic options

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I just started using Django Rest Framework and one of my serializers has a MultipleChoiceField in which the choices are simply all the instances of another model.

Here is the serializer in question:

```
class ObjectTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_field_choices():
        return sorted([
            (p.id, p.name) for p in Parameter.objects.all()
        ])

    object_fields = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=get_field_choices()
    )

    instance_fields = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=get_field_choices()
    )

    labels = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Label.objects.all(),
        many=True, allow_null=True, slug_field='name'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ObjectType
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'object_fields',
                    'instance_fields', 'labels')
```

However, when I add a new Parameter object, the choices are not updated. In regular Django forms, I solved this simply using

```
forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(p.id, p.name) for p in Parameter.objects.all()])
```

and it would update the choices when a new parameter is added without restarting the server. How can I accomplish the same thing with Django Rest Framework serializers?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your choices are models, the most straightforward approach is to use some derivative of `RelatedField`. Given that you're using `p.id`, does `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` work for you? (Please update your question if it doesn't)

If the default behavior (using model's `__unicode__` for the display value) is not what you desire, you can always subclass it and redefine the `display_value` method:

```
class CustomPKRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    """A PrimaryKeyRelatedField derivative that uses named field for the display value."""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.display_field = kwargs.pop("display_field", "name")
        super(CustomPKRelatedField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def display_value(self, instance):
        # Use a specific field rather than model stringification
        return getattr(instance, self.display_field)

...
class ObjectTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    object_fields = CustomPKRelatedField(queryset=Parameter.objects.all(), many=True)
    instance_fields = CustomPKRelatedField(queryset=Parameter.objects.all(), many=True)
    ...
...
```

If all you need is so `BrowsableAPIRenderer` would render a nice-looking `<select>`, I believe that's all you need to do.

---

The `ChoiceField` and `MultipleChoiceField` are designed to work on a static dataset. They even preprocess things at `__init__` to allow grouping. This is why new items don't appear there - those fields essentially "cache" results forever (until the server restart).

If, for some reason, you really need it to be `ChoiceField`-derivative, you can set up `post_save` and `post_delete` singal listeners and update fields' `choices` (and `grouped_choices` if you're not on a very bleeding edge version where a [PR to allow `choices` to be set dynamically](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5426) is already included) attributes. Check the `ChoiceField` [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/c674687782ef96a3bb8466b412e99debd3d04f00/rest_framework/fields.py#L1401) for the details. That would be a dirty hack, though. ;)